# Docker Login: Error when manually logging into private Registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, debian, ubuntu-18.04, docker-registry

I can't manually log into my private GitLab Docker Registry from CLI:

```
# docker login -u "${DOCKER_USER}" -p "${DOCKER_PASS}" "${DOCKER_URL}"
error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`
```

System info:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- docker-ce 18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu (from official repo, without install script)

There is no `~/.docker/config.json` for any users and I'm executing the `docker login` as root.
On Google, I just find recommendations to `export DISPLAY`... Can docker only login to remote registries in a GUI environment?
Exporting DISPLAY=0:0 yields:

```
error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)`
```

Am I missing some dependency? Docker runs fine otherwise, but login doesn't work. I know there are backends to store credentials, but I don't want to store credentials. I'm just trying to authenticate against my registry to pull an image, doesn't that work in Docker ootb?

Comment: FYI: I installed docker-credential-pass as a workaround, which comes with its own bugs. Seems to me like `docker login` only works on GUI systems...

Answer (score 25):

The [`docker-compose`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker-compose/+bug/1796119) package unnecessarily depend on the broken [`golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers/+bug/1794307) package. Removing the executable fixes this.

```
rm /usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice
```

Note: This is a workaround and will need to be repeated each time the package is updated.

This affects the Ubuntu 18.04 (and possibly other non-LTS releases) and some [Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=910822) [releases](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=910823).

Comment: Suddenly your docker-compose retag suggestion makes sense.

Comment: I work with docker & docker swarm, and due to this uninstalled docker-compose before, but still I had to remove the above to make it work.

Comment: Worked for me too. This is still not solved by docker?

Comment: @Sunchezz It is an bug in the Ubuntu (possibly from the upstream Debian package) package, I don't think the package from Docker has the issue...