# "Error saving credentials" in docker login

Tags: docker, ubuntu, cloud

I am executing the next command:

```
docker login
```

And the result that I get is:

```
 Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: 
 `Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`
```

I am using an instance in Oracle Cloud that is:

```
Canonical-Ubuntu-16.04-2018.06.18-0
```

I tried fix it tipping the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg openbox
```

Any idea about what is happening here??

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51153265/1837991

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Login: Error when manually logging into private Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153265/docker-login-error-when-manually-logging-into-private-registry)

Answer (score 38):

This [tip](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/439#issuecomment-461836102) works for me (Ubuntu 18.04):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -V install gnupg2 pass
```

Answer (score 6):

for me helped this comment
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6023

> don't do apt install docker-compose and if you did, remove it and its
> dependencies

```
sudo apt remove docker-compose -y && sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: This fix my issue too

Answer (score 3):

Today i had the same issue after installing docker.io and docker-compose on a fresh ubuntu.
After reading the link posted by Ryabchenko Alexander i tried the command he posted.

I then found out, if you remove docker-compose and reinstalling it, everything started to work like expected.
So my solution to overcome this issue in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt remove docker-compose -y && sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install docker-compose -y
```

Please check out the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55124982/3453279) of Ryabchenko Alexander for the link and reasons why this issue exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `golang-docker-credential-helpers` installed, you need to uninstall that:

```
sudo apt remove golang-docker-credential-helpers
```

That has solved the issue for me.
See also: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6023#issuecomment-434041567

Answer (score -2):

Fixed, it was a problem that dinstalling docker-compose some libraries were removed